# is there a way to check if the cd drive has a CD with python

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi, raspbian, cd-rom

I'm trying to make a program that checks when a cd is inserted with the specific name "PlayMe" and then have the program play the one track on it. The computer is a raspberry pi4 with raspbian.

I have tried just scanning for when the file tree appears, and it works once but when the disc is physically removed it still has the tree.I have also tried using pygame's cdrom method to `get_empty` and `get_name`. I don't know of a better way to do this.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

print(pygame.cdrom.get_count())

pygame.cdrom.get_empty(0)
```

When it gets run I get the output from the `cdrom.get_count` as 1 but the get empty gives:

> "AttributeError: module 'pygame.cdrom' has no attribute 'get_empty'"

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but get_empty is a function of a pygame.cdrom.CD object, not of the pygame.cdrom module directly.

Comment: I also ran the same code with 
pygame.cdrom.CD.get_empty(0) and both iterations without the zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no way to test this as my computer does not have a cd drive, but how about something like this? The idea is that you not only have to create a pygame `CD` object, but also call the pygame-specific `init` function for it before it is usable [per the documentation](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/cdrom.html).

```
import pygame

pygame.init()#should also automatically initialize the pygame cdrom module
num_drives = pygame.cdrom.get_count()
if num_drives == 0:
    raise ValueError("Computer does not have a CD-drive")
drive = pygame.cdrom.CD(0)#first drive, probably default?
drive.init()
if not drive.get_empty():
    print("A CD is in this drive")
else:
    print("No CD is in this drive")
drive.quit()
```

Comment: @panther001 No problem, glad it helped!